# Why is CoCreateInstanceFromApp missing from an ARM build over an x64 build?

Tags: c++, arm, directx, directxtk

***This question does not already  have an answer***
I know what an unresolved external symbol means - I'm asking specifically why when building as ARM the DirectX functions are missing for my project. When I build my DirectX project for Raspberry Pi I get the below link errors. **Why is CoCreateInstFromApp missing only for the ARM build**?

The Microsoft documentation on [CoCreateInstanceFromApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstancefromapp) implies it should simply be present in any Windows executable - this is in fact what I see when building x86 or x64 versions of the same project. It ought to be present, since DirectX does support ARM architecture - or have I missed something?

The project is including `d3d11.lib` & `dxgi.lib`, which I presumed it would pick up from the right directory - but get no specific errors about those libraries. The project is C++ in Visual Studio 2017 Pro v15.8.7.

Redacted link error:

> DirectXTK_ARM.lib : error LNK2019: unresolved
> external symbol __imp_CoCreateInstanceFromApp referenced in function
> "long __cdecl CoCreateInstance  ...
>
> DirectXTK_ARM.lib : error LNK2019: unresolved
> external symbol __imp_PropVariantClear ....

---

**More info, if required:**

I have altered this [Desktop Duplication sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Desktop-Duplication-Sample-da4c696a) from Microsoft to do a screen-shot instead of duplication, and thus removed the window code and used [DirectXTK](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) for saving the file. This works great on my desktop and on a Minnowboard (x64 Win10 IoT). But if I try and compile for Raspberry PI (ARM) it fails with the link error:

> DirectXTK_ARM.lib(WICTextureLoader.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved
> external symbol __imp_CoCreateInstanceFromApp referenced in function
> "long __cdecl CoCreateInstance(struct _GUID const &,struct IUnknown
> *,unsigned long,struct _GUID const &,void * *)" (?CoCreateInstance@@YAJABU_GUID@@PAUIUnknown@@K0PAPAX@Z)
>
> DirectXTK_ARM.lib(WICTextureLoader.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved
> external symbol __imp_PropVariantClear referenced in function "long
> __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::CreateTextureFromWIC(struct ID3D11Device *,struct ID3D11DeviceContext *,struct
> IWICBitmapFrameDecode *,unsigned int,enum D3D11_USAGE,unsigned
> int,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int,struct ID3D11Resource *
> *,struct ID3D11ShaderResourceView * *)" (?CreateTextureFromWIC@?A0x2b71c33d@@YAJPAUID3D11Device@@PAUID3D11DeviceContext@@PAUIWICBitmapFrameDecode@@IW4D3D11_USAGE@@IIIIPAPAUID3D11Resource@@PAPAUID3D11ShaderResourceView@@@Z)
> 1

Comment: Generally ``CoCreateInstance`` and ``PropVariantClear`` are part of ``ole32.lib``. For UWP apps, they are also in the ``WindowsApp.lib`` which you should be used to link to every UWP app.

Comment: Thank you - looks promising. It's a console app that I want to run on win10 iot core, so it's not actually a uwp app. adding ole32.lib has made it link and build! Now I need to see if it'll run ... !

Comment: You can also try ``mincore.lib`` as your 'generic' lib.

Comment: ole32.lib did it! - if you stick those comments as an answer I shall accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CoCreateInstance` and `PropVariantClear` are part of `ole32.lib`.

> UWP apps should link with the umbrella `WindowsApp.lib`, but you can also link to umbrella `mincore.lib` for IoT apps.